# cakephp 3 display html according to users role

Tags: php, html, cakephp, cakephp-3.0

I am making a app with cakephp 3. My users have 2 roles, admin and students. The admin can see everything and the student can see and edit only his profile. the roles are a field in the users table in the database.

the ctp files of the admin have many links to do differents actions, like add a new product o delete an user, what i want to do is display this links just to the admin role, but use the same ctp file for students and admins. I have no idea how to do this, if someone can give me an example please.

for example this is the add.ctp file for users:

```
<div class="actions columns large-2 medium-3">
<h3><?= __('Actions') ?></h3>
THIS ARE THE LINKS
<ul class="side-nav">
    <li><?= $this->Html->link(__('List Users'), ['action' => 'index']) ?></li>
    <li><?= $this->Html->link(__('New Clase'), ['controller' => 'Clases', 'action' => 'add']) ?></li>
    <li><?= $this->Html->link(__('List Convenios Usuarios'), ['controller' => 'ConveniosUsuarios', 'action' => 'index']) ?></li>
    <li><?= $this->Html->link(__('New Convenios Usuario'), ['controller' => 'ConveniosUsuarios', 'action' => 'add']) ?></li>
    <li><?= $this->Html->link(__('List Desvinculaciones'), ['controller' => 'Desvinculaciones', 'action' => 'index']) ?></li>
    <li><?= $this->Html->link(__('New Desvinculacione'), ['controller' => 'Desvinculaciones', 'action' => 'add']) ?></li>
    <li><?= $this->Html->link(__('List Historial Alumnos'), ['controller' => 'HistorialAlumnos', 'action' => 'index']) ?></li>
    <li><?= $this->Html->link(__('New Historial Alumno'), ['controller' => 'HistorialAlumnos', 'action' => 'add']) ?></li>
    <li><?= $this->Html->link(__('List Pagos'), ['controller' => 'Pagos', 'action' => 'index']) ?></li>
    <li><?= $this->Html->link(__('New Pago'), ['controller' => 'Pagos', 'action' => 'add']) ?></li>
    <li><?= $this->Html->link(__('List Pedidos'), ['controller' => 'Pedidos', 'action' => 'index']) ?></li>
    <li><?= $this->Html->link(__('New Pedido'), ['controller' => 'Pedidos', 'action' => 'add']) ?></li>
</ul>
<div class="users form large-10 medium-9 columns">
<?= $this->Form->create($user) ?>
<fieldset>
    <legend><?= __('Agrega Nuevo Usuario') ?></legend>
    <?php
        echo $this->Form->input('nombre', ['label'=>'Nombre Completo']);
        echo $this->Form->input('fecha_nac',['label'=>'Fecha de Nacimiento']);
        echo $this->Form->input('username',['label'=>'Nombre de Usuario']);
        echo $this->Form->input('email');
        echo $this->Form->input('password', ['label'=>'Contraseña']);
        echo $this->Form->input('telefono');
        echo $this->Form->input('rol', ['options' =>['Alumno'=>'Alumno', 'Monitor'=>'Monitor','Instructor'=>'Instructor']]);
        echo $this->Form->input('fecha_ing',['label'=>'Fecha de Ingreso']);
        echo $this->Form->input('profesion');
        echo $this->Form->input('grado_id', ['options' => $grados]);
        echo $this->Form->input('referencia');
        echo $this->Form->input('estado', ['options' =>['Activo','Inactivo']]);
        echo $this->Form->input('fecha_ult_acenso', ['label'=>'Fecha último ascenso','empty' => true, 'default' => '']);
        echo $this->Form->input('nombre_apoderado', ['empty' => true, 'default' => 'No tiene Apoderado']);
        echo $this->Form->input('telefono_apoderado',  ['empty' => true, 'default' => '']);
        echo $this->Form->input('nota_salud',['label'=>'Información de Salud', 'empty' => true, 'default' => 'No presenta Complicaciones']);
        echo $this->Form->input('llevar_a', ['label'=>'En caso de Emergencia', 'empty' => true, 'default' => '']);
        echo $this->Form->input('monto_paga',['label'=>'Mensualidad']);
        echo $this->Form->input('id_user_referencia', ['label'=>'Quien Paga']);
        echo $this->Form->input('observaciones', ['empty' => true, 'default' => 'No tiene observaciones']);
        echo $this->Form->input('fecha_cambio_password', ['empty' => true, 'default' => '']);
        echo $this->Form->file('foto');
    ?>
</fieldset>
<?= $this->Form->button(__('Agregar')) ?>
<?= $this->Form->end() ?>
```

My first idea is to use and if in the ctp file and have two list of links and display one or other according to the user's role, but i dont know if there is a better form to do that, using the tools of cakephp.

Comment: You have two cases, and (presumably) a field in the user table saying what role a given user is - test for it your auth logic, and in the template files to output one list of links or another. If you've done nothing so far this question is too broad to answer.

Comment: i edit the question, adding the ctp files like an example

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you only need to show/hide some/all contents(links) in your View(.ctp) file, then I have a better idea.

Just pass a view variable from the controller method for this page which decides whether the current user is admin or student.

For eg.,

In your **controller** method,

```
if( check if user is admin ) {
// set the view variable here
    $this->set('is_admin', 1);
}
```

In your **view**(.ctp file):

```
<? if( isset($is_admin) && $is_admin === 1 ) { ?>
<!-- All the link codes for admin goes here as html -->
    <li><?= $this->Html->link(__('_ _ _'), ['controller' => 'Clases', 'action' => 'add']) ?></li>
<? } ?>
```

> NOTE: Please note that this way only hides the links for students in the view, and not the access to these links.

Comment: How did you checked the the condition?? 

    if( check if user is admin ) {
        // set the view variable here
        $this->set('is_admin', 1);
    }

You are checking condition in view file then what does these above lines of code? Need clarification